# Matches across multiple rows without many joins

Tags: mysql

I'm having a performance issue with a specific piece of my database as it has grown. I have a table something like:

```
itemID | name   | value
2      | action | throw
1      | thing  | ball
3      | looks  | dumb
2      | thing  | stick
3      | thing  | rock
1      | action | hit
4      | looks  | grey
1      | action | wedge
3      | action | throw
```

I need to query this table for item IDs that match onw of more name having one or more names (AND) with one or one or more values (OR). To date I've accomplished this with an OR like:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM features as t1
    LEFT JOIN features as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
(
     (t1.`name` = 'thing' AND t1.`value` LIKE 'ball') 
  OR (t1.`name` = 'thing' AND t1.`value` LIKE 'stick')
) 
AND
(
        t2.`name` = 'action' 
   AND (t2.`value` LIKE 'hit' OR t2.`value` LIKE 'thro%')
)
```

*Note that in this example each name has 2 values, but there could be any number.
I have [this sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43fe73/2) if it helps clarify.

This worked fine for a while but as the system evolved these tables have gotten large (sometimes over 4 million rows) and, more problematically, the queries running on them have from to include many name/value sets. Performance drops dramatically after the 4th JOIN and by 9 it can take over a minute for queries to execute. I've also had issues with queries freezing in the STATISTICS step for hours which I have bandaided by setting the optimizer depth to 1, but that is less than ideal.

How can I perform this query without so many joins?

**edit:** I missed one of the requirements when I made the question (case of the Monday's). The queried values in the value column need to case insensitive and wildcards are a possibility. I have edited my query example accordingly.

Comment: Please post the execution plan. You might just be missing a couple of indexes (`EXPLAIN <your current query here>`.

Comment: which one is your primary key in this table ?

Comment: It appears that you have a design issue with your table.  instead of a column "name" you should have three columns "action", "thing", and "looks".

Comment: There is no primary key on the table bu there is an index on the ID column.

@DwB In pratice there are thousands of possible names that change 3 or more times a day, it's not at all practical to make them all columns.

Comment: consider adding an index for the name and the value columns.  This will cause a balancing act between the amount of overhead required for the index (if you have many updates and/or inserts) versus the overhead of two or more full table scans each time you run the query.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
SELECT id 
FROM features f
group by name
having sum(name = 'thing' and value in ('ball', 'stick')) > 0
or sum(name = 'action' and value in ('hit', 'throw')) > 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43fe73/4)

Comment: I believe this would have worked for the question as asked (thank you) but I missed an important requirement that the value column matches need to be case insensitive and support wildcard which (as far as I know) rules out IN clauses. I'm doing testing now using a string of nested ORs, if that works out I'll let you know.